# Toshiba Satellite C55t-B5109 Won't open BIOS

Tags: boot, laptop, bios

I recently wiped my laptop's hard drive, and have reinstalled Windows 8.1 on it, but my BIOS won't open. I have done all the steps I had done before to get into BIOS, disable fast startup in Windows 8, spam F2, then F12, then held them, and still, I cannot get into my BIOS unless I go through Windows 8.1 troubleshoot mode and get into BIOS there. I have also tried re-installing the latest version which I already had, and it wont because it says I already have it. Is there any way I can get my BIOS to boot from my F2, there seems to be no other case like it I have found... can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

1. Do a full shutdown of Windows, not the "hybrid" shutdown e.g. in a Command dialog type **shutdown -s -f -t 0**. Holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while shutting down normally may also work.
2. Hold <kbd>F2</kbd> *before* you power up and keep it pressed, *then*
3. Press the power key to start up, releasing <kbd>F2</kbd> after BIOS screen appears.

See also [Toshiba's tips on BIOS](http://forums.toshiba.com/t5/General-Troubleshooting/Toshiba-Satellite-C55-A5310-Bios-Settings-Key-Combo/td-p/518767).

Comment: Nothing, nothing at all. It worked just fine before, now it doesn't open BIOS. ugggg.

Comment: Sorry about that... at least you state you can access it hrough Windows 8.1 troubleshoot mode. Hopefully, it's not malware in UEFI -- see https://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-07/Heasman/Presentation/bh-usa-07-heasman.pdf